# How to query posts from single post format on Genesis framework

Tags: wp-query, post-formats

How to query posts from single post format on Genesis framework?   I want to just show posts from **gallery post** format only.

I tried this query:

```
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query(
    "taxonomy=post-format&field=slug&terms=post_format-link&posts_per_page=‌​5"
); 
while($recent->have_posts()) : 
$recent->the_post();
?>
```

But I didn’t get what I wanted.

Comment: Isn't there a Genesis support forum?

Comment: no replies there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taxonomy should be `post_format` and term should be `post-format-link`. Also simple taxonomy queries are deprecated since 3.1 in favor of `tax_query`:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-link'
        )
    )
);
$recent = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I did that. mistyped here :(

Comment: your query is still wrong, use the code I've posted here. old query string style taxonomy arguments are `taxonomy` and `term` (not plural), and `slug` is not a valid argument. you should be using `tax_query` instead anyway.